# How to remove elements of an array based on value fast and efficiently (VBA)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, element

I want to remove elements of a 2D array(1 to n,1 to 1) based on a value. in order to do that systematically we should create a function like **RemoveElementsFromArray_ByValue(Arr As Variant, value As Variant)**. My question is how to efficiently code this function in order to perform fast even for big arrays and in other main subs easily.
Note that there could be more than one element with that value that should be removed.
Assume we want to use this function in the following Sub to remove elements of arrays Xi,Yi that respectively have the values equal to any of the elements of the arrays Xi_Inf,Yi_Inf and put the results in arrays Xii,Yii and print the pairs(Xii,Yii):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Xi(1 To 5, 1), Yi(1 To 5, 1 to 1) As Long
    Dim Xii(), Yii()
    Dim Xi_Inf(1 To 2, 1), Yi_Inf(1 To 2, 1 to 1) As Long
    Dim i, j As Long
    
    Xi(1, 1) = 1: Yi(1, 1) = 2
    Xi(2, 1) = 2: Yi(2, 1) = 5
    Xi(3, 1) = 6: Yi(3, 1) = 20
    Xi(4, 1) = 10: Yi(4, 1) = 7
    Xi(5, 1) = 15: Yi(5, 1) = 45

    Xi_Inf(1, 1) = 6: Yi_Inf(1, 1) = 20
    Xi_Inf(2, 1) = 15: Yi_Inf(2, 1) = 45

    n = UBound(Xi, 1): m = UBound(Xi_Inf, 1)
    ReDim Xii(1 To n, 1 To 1): ReDim Yii(1 To n, 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To n
        Xii(i, 1) = Xi(i, 1): Yii(i, 1) = Yi(i, 1) 'start with Xi,Yi
    Next
           
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To m
            If Xi(i, 1) = Xi_Inf(j, 1) Then
                Xii = RemoveElementsFromArray_ByValue((Xii), (Xi_Inf(j, 1)))
                Yii = RemoveElementsFromArray_ByValue((Yii), (Xi_Inf(j, 1)))
            Else
                'do nothing to Xii,Yii
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
        
    For i = 1 To n - m
        Debug.Print "(" & Xii(i, 1) & "," & Yii(i, 1) & ")"
    Next
End Sub
```

I expect this result:

```
(1,2)
(2,5)
(10,7)
```

Assume we defined a function RemoveElementFromArray_ByIndex(Arr1 As Variant, Index As Long) that removes an element from an array based on an index as following:

```
Function RemoveElementFromArray_ByIndex(Arr1 As Variant, Index As Long)
    Dim UB1, LB1 As Long
    Dim Arr2() As Variant
    Dim i, k As Long
    
    UB1 = UBound(Arr1, 1): LB1 = LBound(Arr1, 1)
    
    ReDim Arr2(LB1 To UB1 - 1, 1 To 1)
    
    If Index < LB1 Or Index > UB1 Then
        MsgBox "The index is out of range!", vbExclamation
    ElseIf Index = LB1 Then
        k = LB1
        For i = LB1 To UB1 - 1
            Arr2(k, 1) = Arr1(i + 1, 1)
            k = k + 1
        Next i
    ElseIf Index > LB1 And Index < UB1 Then
        k = LB1
        For i = LB1 To Index - 1
            Arr2(k, 1) = Arr1(i, 1)
            k = k + 1
        Next i
        k = Index
        For i = Index To UB1 - 1
            Arr2(k, 1) = Arr1(i + 1, 1)
            k = k + 1
        Next i
    ElseIf Index = UB1 Then
        k = LB1
        For i = LB1 To UB1 - 1
            Arr2(k, 1) = Arr1(i, 1)
            k = k + 1
        Next i
    End If
    RemoveElementFromArray_ByIndex = Arr2
End Function
```

Should we make use of that function here or basically seek another different idea?!.
Please help me to find the best function **RemoveElementsFromArray_ByValue**.

Comment: Since the condition of the array is to have 1 column, you can iterate through the array and store results that do not match the value to a collection. Then clear the array and redim using the count in the collection, then reload.

Comment: In the first procedure `ReDim arr(1 To n, 1)` is two columns (if `Option Base` isn't `1`). You should rather do `ReDim arr(1 To n, 1 To 1)`. Also, `Dim i As Long, j As Long`: every variable 'needs' an `As`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 your'e right. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to achieve this. Below example will paste all matching values from colA and colB to colC but you can easily inverse the logic, add blanks instead of skipping the value and convert to a function.

```
    Sub DictMatch()
        Dim Arr, Arr2, j As Long, i As Long, dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create dictionary lateB
        With dict 'used because I'm to lazy to retype dict everywhere :)
            .CompareMode = 1 'textcompare
            Arr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2 'load source
            For j = 1 To UBound(Arr) 'traverse source
                If Not .exists(Arr(j, 1)) Then 'set key if I don't have it yet in dict
                    .Add Key:=Arr(j, 1), Item:=Arr(j, 1)
                End If
            Next j
            ReDim Arr2(1 To UBound(Arr), 1 To 1)  'size the target array, just 2 cols
            i = 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(Arr)
                If .exists(Arr(j, 2)) Then 'matching happens here, compare data from target with dictionary
                    Arr2(j, 1) = Arr(j, 2) 'write to target array if match
                End If
            Next j
        End With
        With Sheet1
            .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(UBound(Arr2), 3)).Value2 = Arr2 'dump target array to sheet
        End With
    End Sub
```